# Extract msg attachment from eml file

Tags: c#, mapi, outlook-redemption

I am trying to extract an MSG file from an EML attachment, I can get the script to produce the name of the attachment but I cannot figure out how I get the attachment to be saved to the PST rather than the EML, my code looks as follows

```
session = new RDOSession(); 
session.LogonPstStore(C:\\temp\\outputfile.pst);                    
var mail = RdoFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Mail");
mail.Sent = true;
mail.Import(C:\\temp\\randomfile.eml, 1024);
mail.Save();
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean an embedded message attachment from the EML file that you are importing? So you want to import the embedded message attachment only but not its parent message?

Comment: Hi yes that’s correct, I have EJF messages so they have the original message attached as an SJF file. I have since added a variable that gets populated by running mail. Attachments and I can see the MSG file name, just not sure now how I can pull that out and push it into the PST.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but need to use the `.EmbeddedMsg` `property` to get the MSG file. Example code below.

```vb
Dim fileItmName As String 'The fullname of the EML file including path
Dim RMsg, AMsg

'Outlook folder
Set fldrOutlook = RSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("[Subfolder]").Folders("[Subfolder]")  'etc.

'Bring EML message into Outlook (you can delete it after you pull the attachment)
Set RMsg = fldrOutlook.Items.Add
RMsg.Sent = True
RMsg.Import fileItmName, 1024
RMsg.Save

'find msg attachment
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachment-object-outlook
For Each attch In RMsg.Attachments
    If Right(attch.FileName, 4) = ".msg" Then 'In case the EML message has more than one attachment.
        Set AMsg = attch.EmbeddedMsg 'This is the MSG message you are trying to get.

        'Process the message

    end if


Next attch
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the outer message, you need to get to the inner message first. Call `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile` to create a temporary MSG file (you can delete it later), import the outer message using `RDOMail.Import`, loop through the attachments and use `RDOAttachment.EmbeddedMsg` (return RDOMail object). You can then copy that message using `RDOMail.CopyTo()`, passing either your newly created (`mail`) object or the target folder (`RdoFolder`).